# How would you translate Socialism/Communism into Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, politics

Note that both socialism and communist have been synonyms their appearance in the romance Sprachen until the end of the times, unless you believe Stalin's lies. Therefore both a word based in the stem* *societás* or *commúnistás* would work.

After reading some comments I am considering to use some derivation from the word sociális, So far I am preferring with the abstract affix -ia (genitive -iae) rather than the abstract affix -tús (genitive -tútis) e.i. sociálisia.

So far the candidate list goes:

1. sociália
2. sociálitús
3. sociálismus
4. commúnisia
5. commúnistús
6. commúnismus

But I am worried about hidden meaning like what @Arfrever mentions whith respect to socius meaning companion/ally. Neverless the Spanish Language has the term socio and socialismo, both coming from the Latin societás with socio meaning companion/ally and socialismo meaning socialism.

Comment: *Socius* is a Latin word, so would *socialismus* do?

Comment: @TKR And there's some support online for it: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/socialismus#Latin

Comment: @TKR No because ismus is a greek affix

Comment: The Romans certainly weren't averse to using Greek morphemes, especially for technical terms.

Comment: @Draconis How would I do it with a latin affix?

Comment: I would be more concerned with modern French/English terms *socialism(e)*, *social* having somehow different meanings from Latin *socius* ("companion, ally"), *sociālis* ("pertaining to companionship, allies"), than with Greek-origin suffix.

Comment: Some native Latin suffixes to form abstract nouns from adjectives are *-ia* (genitive *-iae*) and *-tūs* (genitive *-tūtis*).

Comment: @Arfrever some another hidden meanings with latin socialismus und commúnismus?

Comment: Anyway these terms are already used in Latin Wikipedia: [Socialismus](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialismus), [Communismus vel coenonismus](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communismus).

Comment: @Arfrever I whan the hidden meanings anyway, specially considering, that I don't take seriously wikipedia in any measure.

Comment: In his Politeia, Aristotle mocks Plato for his idea of an oligarchy in which, in addition to land, cattle and silver, women, craftsmen, children and slaves are common property, too. As an example he cites the poleis in Dorian Crete. There are no 1:1 maps of modern political terms back to communities in the time of the Pharaohs. They split up into elements mapped to innumerable systems of local constitutions with fast changes over a millenium.

Comment: @RolandF It don't exactly care details of the word for the doctrine of public of the means of production, just that platon's oligarchy, the SDP, Democrats, the central planing board, the Soviet Union, all of them are included. Don't ever mention that I am willing to blend the term in this case.

Comment: When deriving words (here deriving noun with suffix *-ia*), inflectional ending from base word would be removed, and there is possibility that at least part of derivational suffix from base word would be removed. *sociālis* = *soci-āli-s* = *socio-* + [*-āli-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-alis#Latin) (derivational suffix) + *-s* (nominative singular ending). So the longest possibility is *sociālis* + *-ia* → *sociālia*. Analogically *sociālis* + *-tūs* → *sociālitūs*, *commūnis* + *-ia* → *commūnia*, *commūnis* + *-tūs* → *commūnitūs*.

Comment: [*-ismus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ismus#Latin) would be divisible as *-ismu-* (or rather *-ismo-*) + *-s*, and its *is* is not Latin *-is* suffix. More etymology [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ισμός#Ancient_Greek) and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ίζω#Ancient_Greek). So this *is* in *-ismus* is ultimately from PIE \**idi̯* (= \**idj*; I dislike IPA-incompatible usage of letter *y* for [palatal approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palatal_approximant)). (As [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel) says, diacritic ̯ is generic marker of semivowels.)

Comment: @Arfrever don't understand your comment about -ismus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to be understood by people there is no reasonable translation aside from *sociālismus* and *commūnismus*, which are in fact the terms people do use, e.g. on Vicipaedia (as pointed out in the comments by Arfrever).

It's true *-ismus* is ultimately a borrowing from Greek -ισμός, but it's been a first-class citizen in Latin for two millennia now, and the kind of linguistic purism that tries to shun Greek loans has never really been a feature of the language. Trying to calque the terms with a native suffix is both anachronistic and counterproductive.